# C Program To Display Numbers In Ascending Order

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I know how to do the counting in ascending order. Before doing it in another approach, I've done the following with `for Loop`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int i;

   for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
   {
     printf("%d", i);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

And the above just works fine. So I was trying to do it using `while loop` and stuck with the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, number = 10;

    while(i <= number)
    {
       i = number;
    }
    i++;

    printf("%d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** I can understand the above is a bad one and should be avoided. It's so simple but I would be happy to know what wrong have I done. I tried to debug and it shows 38 with `while loop`.

Comment: i++ should be inside while loop

Comment: you must initialize `i` to `1`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @greenshade. But if I do so, it becomes 37.

Comment: `int i = 1, number = 10;

    while(i <= number)
    {
       printf("%d", i++);
    }`

Comment: Does The answer below solved your query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This for loop

```
for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
```

can be converted to a while loop the following way. The expression

```
i = 1;
```

(that is the initialization of the variable `i`) will be placed before the while loop. The condition

```
i <= 10
```

will be used as the condition of the while loop.

And at last the expression `i++` will be used in the body of the loop as its last statement. Combining all this together you will get

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int i;

    i = 1;

    while( i <= 10 )
    {
        printf("%d ", i);
        i++
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thus if you have a for loop like

```
for ( expression1 ; condition2 ; expression3 ) 
{
    statements
}
```

then in general you can convert it to an equivalent while loop the following way

```
expression1;

while ( condition2 )
{
    statements
    expression3;
}
```

If a for loop contains some `continue` statements then you will need to include `expression3` before each continue statement in the corresponding while loop..

Another approach relative to your original while loop is to combine the condition and the third expression in a condition. In this case the initial value of the variable `i` should be equal to 0. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int i;

    i = 0;

    while( ++i <= 10 )
    {
        printf("%d ", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As for this program

```
include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, number = 10;

    while(i <= number)
    {
       i = number;
    }
    i++;

    printf("%d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

then it has undefined behavior because the variable `i`  is not initialized. And at least these statement

```
i++;

printf("%d", i);
```

must be inside the body of the loop and the statement

```
i = number;
```

must be removed.

Take into account that according to the C Standard function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Answer (score 3):

Your while loop may look like this :

```
int main(void) {
    int i = 1, number = 10; // initialize i to 1

    while(i <= number)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        i++;   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialized `i` to some value. So it contains a **garbage value**.

Also `i++` should be inside the while loop. Otherwise it will  become an infinite loop if the garbage value of `i` is less than 10

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialized `i` to `1`. Also You have not included `i++` in loop. 
What you wanted to do was run the while loop till `i` becomes equal to `10` , so to do that you have to increment `i` with each iteration of loop  , also you have incorrectly done `i = number`, maybe you wanted to `printf("%d" , i)` With This Your Code Becomes

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 1, number = 10;

    while (i <= number)
    {
       printf("%d", i);
       i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output : `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

After `10` , `i` is more than `number`(which is equal to `10`) so loop stop.

Comment: You do not need two `printf`s.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to affect or initialize `i`. If you don't the C standard say it's undefined behavior.

```
int i = 0; // for example
```

By the way, in your case the correct prototype for main is `int main(void);`

Answer (score 1):

The variable `i` must be initialized to 1. In addition `i++` should be in the loop. Not sure why you are assigning number to i at each iteration.
Your code changed:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i =1;
    int number = 10;

    while(i <= number)
    {
       i = number;  // why are you assigning 10 to i?
       i++;
    }


    printf("%d", i);

    return 0;
}
```